# SendGrid loop issue... why does it die after one

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have been everywhere on Stack and help docs but I am confused I must say.
**Can you only make one API call at a time using SendGrid?**

```
    <some for each loop>{
     $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
     ADD elements to the $email from the loop
     $sendgrid = new \SendGrid('APIKEY');  
            try {
               $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
              } catch (Exception $e) {
               echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
               }
  } // close for each loop
```

This only runs for the first iteration of the loop. I know that SendGrid wants you to use addTo etc.. to send to multiple recipients. I get that but in some instances this loop needs to be called over and over because it is inside yet another loop. What do I do if I have to run through a SendGrid call more then once on the same page? Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Please give us more context. Since you have issues with the iterations, we need to see all loops and what any variable you iterate actually contains, or we won't have a clue what's going on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'd like to if it were that easy. I am looping through WP multisites and pulling Gravity Forms entries from those sites. The loop works perfectly and outputs what I need UNTIL I add the SendGrid piece. It dies after sending the first email. It SHOULD be able to loop correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you saying that "the loop works perfectly" while asking us why the loop only runs once, doesn't really make it any clearer. Even if you think it's irrelevant, we need to see it. We need to be able to get the bigger picture. Please add _all_ relevant code related to the loops.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for making me look more closely at my code. As I was creating the looping sequence I noticed that I had a variable $email defined in two different places. The error indeed was in the loop and not in SendGrid. Thanks again for some tough love. Much respect.